# Display images from sql database in winforms c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm creating a library of Videos and I am unsure how to display all of the videos stored on my database onto a windows form. The database includes the VideoTitle, VideoURL and VideoImageURL so I would like to display all of the users Videos onto the winform in a view type where you can see the Image. Through my research I've found that Picture boxes within a Flow Layout Panel would be possible.

Would something like this work?

```
foreach (string image in images)
{
   PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
   picture.Image = new Bitmap(image); 
   FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(picture);
}
```

In my case the user would have several videos so i'm stuck on how to display it. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `VideoImageURL` contain? A local path or a remote resource (as `https://etc/some.png`)? Anyway, use the [PictureBox.ImageLocation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation). In any case, focus on your app's design: how would you present the list of movies and how are the details of a movie shown when a User picks one from the list? Do you need to show more than one Image? Is it *interactive* (e.g., when clicked, it's shown in its full size, so you're initially showing thumbnails)? The design will then determine the tools needed.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for the reply! VideoImageURL contains a local path to an image. I would like to present the list of movies in a basic format where all the videos are listed side by side with a vertical scroller if the amount of videos fills the page. Upon clicking in the videos it will play the VideoURL through the windows media player that I am using in the application.